# set up this triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$D=${$ x^2-4(y^2+z^2)\ge{0} \  ,2x^2+y^2+z^2 \le{1} $}

- So I have a double cone on the x axes
- and an Ellipsoid

I have to compute $\int_{D}|x|(1+yz)dxdydz$

**[UPDATE]**

I think this is the way to proceed:

$\int_{D}|x|(1+yz)dV = \int_{D}x(1+yz)dV-\int_{D}x(1+yz)dV$

for the first integral, I took the x range :

$x=(range)= [2\sqrt{y^2+z^2},\sqrt{1-y^2/2-z^2/2}]$

In order to simplify the integral I change to cylindrical coordinates:

$x_r =(range)=[2r,\sqrt{1-r^2}/\sqrt{2}]$

eventually : ($1/3$ is the radius of the circle about the intersection of the cone and the ellipsoid)

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1/3}\int_{2r}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}/\sqrt{2}}{x(1+r^2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta})rdxdrd\theta}$

the integral seems kinda wrong, what do you think ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that by symmetry of $D$, we have

$$\int_D |x|yz \, dV = 0$$

as the signs of $y$ and $z$ will cancel each other out over different octants.

Hence the quantity of interest is just \begin{align}\int_D |x| \, dV &\end{align}

We can focus on just on the first octant and then multiply it by $8$.

\begin{align}
&\int_D |x| \, dV \\&= 8 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_{0}^{\frac13}\int_{2r}^{\sqrt{\frac{1-r^2}2}}xr\,\,\, dx dr d\theta \\
&=4 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^\frac13r\left(\frac{1-r^2}{2} -4r^2\right)\,\,  dr d\theta \\
&=4 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^\frac13r\left(\frac{1-9r^2}{2} \right)\,\,  dr d\theta \\
&=\pi \int_0^\frac13r\left(1-9r^2 \right)\,  dr  \\
&= \pi \left[ \frac{r^2}2-\frac{9r^4}{4}\right]_0^\frac13\\
&= \pi \left[ \frac1{18}-\frac1{36} \right]\\
&= \frac{\pi}{36}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. one more little question : did you take the positive value for the absolute value becouse you were doing the positive first octant ? $|x|=x$

Comment: yup, over the first octant, we have $|x|=x$.

Comment: $2 \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac13}\int_{2r}^{\sqrt{\frac{1-r^2}2}}xr\,\,\, dx dr d\theta $ would this be still correct ?

Comment: yes, rather than considering $8$ octants, you consider positive $x$ and negative $x$ separately, which is equivalent, it will give you the same value.